# JavaScript code in HTML in a support page in a site

Tags: javascript, html, text, textbox, datalist

I want a box to give suggestions with the post titles while typing. I made this initial code:

```
<form action="control()" method="post">
<input name="keyword" id="search_input" autocomplete="off" list="tips" placeholder="Describe your problem"/> 

      <datalist id="tips">        
      <option value="titleofpost1"></option>  
      <option value="titleofpost2"></option>        
      [...]
      </datalist>

<input type="submit" value="invia">
```

and then a JavaScript function such as:

```
function control() {
  if (search_input == word_of_post)
[...]
```

And so I ask you two things:

- How do you make the datalist's suggestions appear after the first letter and not when you click on the input? (because there will be so many posts)
- How do you get results similar to what is written even if they are not the same?

This is the code:

```
    <table  height="30%" border="0" bgcolor="white" width="100%" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 5px solid white;">
    <tr><td width="50%" align="center" colspan="2"><br/><div class="title"><h1>Ciao, come possiamo aiutarti?</h1></div> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td width="9.85%"></td><td height="70%">
    
    <form id="search_form" action="???" method="post">
        <fieldset id="search_field"><center><table border="0" height="100%" width="100%"><tr><td width="10%" align="center">
        <input type="image" src="immagini/lente.jpg"/></td><td width="2%"></td>
        <td height="100%" width="88%" align="center">
        <input name="keyword" id="search_input" list="tips" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Describe your problem" width="100%" height="100%" style="outline:none;"/></td></tr></table></center>
        </fieldset>

<datalist id="tips">        
      <option value="titleofpost1"></option>  
      <option value="titleofpost2"></option>        
      [...]
      </datalist>

    </form>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
```

I haven't done a JavaScript code yet, could you give me an example? THANKS
[Image of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPt0R.png)

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] of your attempts. As it is now, we cannot guess what the expected result is. You can also paste an image example of the output

Comment: action="control()"  is not going to do anything - you need to use `document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("input",control)` for example

Comment: Can you help me with this code?? pleaseee...